# Calculating ex unit in px

Tags: css

```css
#mainContent p {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    color: #000;
    margin: 1ex 0;
}
```

I've met this code in a project. When I got to check this on **devtool** of **Chrome** I found that `margin: 1ex 0` gives the following, `margin-top: 6.9328px` `margin-bottom: 6.9328px` `margin-right: 0` `margin-left: 0`

My question is, what equation was used to get **1ex** to equal `6.9328px`?

Comment: just googled and got this information https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Comment: The information is contained in the font, that is, it's stored somewhere in the font file, and it's different for each font. So there is no equation.

Comment: There is a little trick called [font-size-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust) which you may be able to make use of - basically it allows you to set your own `ex` size. But beware that it currently does not work in IE or Edge.